# Why do I get this makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target 'makefile'. Stop

Tags: java, makefile, command-line, jar

I am trying to create a jar file using the **make** command on Windows PowerShell. I downloaded https://chocolatey.org/packages/make to install the make package onto windows. Here is what my make file looks like:

```
        output: Main.class second.class
        jar cvf output.jar Main.class second.class

        Main.class: Main.java
        javac Main.java

        second.class: second.java
                      javac second.java
```

I saved the file in notepad as **makefile** and I made sure it didn't have the .txt extension. These are also the two java programs (Main and second), I have in notepad:

Main:

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println("Hello world!");
   }
}
```

second:

```
public class second{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      System.out.println("Just google it");
   }
}
```

Note: These 3 files, makefile, Main.java, and second.java are all stored in one folder.

When I open Windows Powershell and went to the folder where these 3 files are located and typed:

```
make makefile
```

I get this error:

**make: *** No rule to make target 'makefile'.  Stop.**

Comment: What happens if you just type `make` rather than `make makefile`.  By typing `make makefile` you specify `makefile` as the target.

Comment: @G.M. I just did that and I got the same error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Should I type: make Main.java second.java When I do that, I get these responses:      make: Nothing to be done for 'Main.java'.
make: Nothing to be done for 'second.java'

Comment: That is not the same error.  G.M. is correct, the command `make makefile` is wrong.  At the same prompt where you type `make` (by itself with no arguments), type `dir` and make sure that the file `makefile` with no extensions exists in that directory.

Comment: You don't type `make Main.java` because that file is your source file, it already exists.  Make doesn't have to do anything to build it.  The arguments you give to make are the _output_ that you want make to build.  If you don't give it any arguments, it will use the first target that appears in your makefile.  For your makefile the first target is `output` so make will try to build that, assuming that it can find the makefile.